# Azure Mobile Services publish target missing

Tags: azure-mobile-services

In Azure portal, I have created a new mobile service with Xamarin/Android platform and able to download sample 'Todolist' solution.

When I open the sample solution in Visual Studio 2012 (or 2013) then right click on 'Service' project to choose 'Publish' there is no publish target named 'Azure Mobile Services' to select. I am only able to publish to 'Azure Web Sites' only which is wrong target.

Any helps?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you running? The "Publish->Mobile Service" gesture was added in VS 2013 Update 1, I believe. You can check your version from Help->About Visual Studio.

Comment: Ok. It is solved when I use VS 2013 Update 4. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I got a project from my Azure Mobile Service

[image]
And then I publish it without problems

[image]

Can you confirm that you did the same? And each type of project you got?

Did you got the HTML/JS, and now you are publishing it? Looks like that is....otherwise I think is impossible to publish to Web Sites.

Comment: At step 1, I didn't choose Windows platform. I chose Xamarin platform. And when I select 'Publish...', it only appears 'Azure Web Sites', do not have 'Microsoft Azure Mobile Services' like you.

Comment: Further more, I am still able to publish to 'Mobile Services' if I use Windows platform, but when I chose Xamarin, it is not.

Comment: I got the sample project from Xamarin version and both push to AMS.